# Не работает in_array в php. Что делаю не так?

Tags: php

Есть код, но почему-то не работает функция in_array. Мне кажется что ничего не упустил (значит что-то точно упустил), но не могу понять что именно. Вот сам код:

```php
$search = $_POST[search];
$filename = "users.txt";
$file = fopen($filename, "r");
$pre_list = fread($file, filesize($filename));
$list = explode("||" ,$pre_list);
foreach($list as $sid=>$value);
if (in_array("$search",$value) == 1)
     echo "Найдено совпадение с $search";
else echo "Совпадений с $search не найдено";

fclose($file);
```

Comment: `if_array` или же `in_array`?

Comment: 1) начните с кавычек в post; 2) обратите внимание на пустое тело цикла 3) и подумайте массивом ли вообще является ваше value на момент сравнения 4) для чтения файла в строки есть более простые варианты

Comment: @4500zenja в самом коде же `in_array`, чего на заголовки смотреть

Comment: @4500zenja да, ошибся в заголовке, исправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение! Убрал foreach, в нём не было необходимости вообще!
Проблема была в том, что в файл данные записывались с пробелом после "||", а искались без пробела. Вот работающий код:

```
$filename = "users.txt";
  $file = fopen($filename, "r");
  $pre_list = fread($file, filesize($filename));
  $list = explode("||" ,$pre_list);
  //foreach($list as $sid=>$value);
if (in_array($search,$list) == true)
         {echo "Найдено совпадение с $search<br>";}
else {echo "Совпадений с $search не найдено<br>";}
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 1):

Код не работает потому, что после foreach запятая)

```
foreach($list as $sid=>$value);
```

А должны быть фигурные скобки

```
foreach($list as $sid=>$value)
{
if (in_array("$search",$value) == 1)
     echo "Найдено совпадение с $search";
else echo "Совпадений с $search не найдено";
}
```

Comment: у него `$value` - строка а не массив, это вас не смущает?

Comment: Это он сам увидит, когда код хоть дойдет до того места)